# C++ Overloading operator +()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a simple class called String which has as a private field a char*.

```
class String {
      char *s;
+ some public methods
};
```

I want to overload the + operator so a + b would mean that the strings from a and b are concatenated.

The function is here:

```
String String::operator+(String a)
{
    String rez;
    rez.s = new char[strlen(this->s) + strlen(a.s) + 1];
    assert(rez.s);
    strcpy(rez.s, this->s);
    strcat(rez.s, a.s);
    cout<<rez.s<<endl; // HERE rez.s CONTAINS THE RIGHT STRING!
    return rez;
}
```

After I call this:
c = a + b;

i get an error called Debug assertion failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you are trying ot do is not constructor overloading, but operator overloading.

Comment: Also do 'a' and 'b' contain real strings? You may be calling strlen on NULL or uninitialized pointers.

Comment: `typedef String std::string;`

Comment: If you're going to implement your own string class IMO you ought to at least make it 8-bit clean (i.e. not-null terminated).

Comment: I'm guessing [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, read up on the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)

Then, consider this:

```
class String {
      char *s;   // << pointer
+ some public methods
};
```

"+ some public methods" better have a constructor that initializes the pointer member to a testable value (like NULL) or you're well-into undefined behavior. It better override the copy-constructor and assignment operators to properly duplicate the string from one String object to another. Finally, it better have a destructor that knows how to clean up a dynamic pointer to the content allocated in all of the above.

I **strongly** suggest you read that article backwards and forwards.

Comment: I didn't have a copy constructor. In my function rez was exactly what I wanted but I was returning the pointer that was deleted by destructor at the end of the function. Thank you!